# WPF DataGrid Text Search Not Working after Cell Alignment Change

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am working on the DataGrid text search feature based on the sample code from the forum. For my case, there are no fixed columns and depending on the data from SQL query.

All are working fine until I change the cell alignment of the column in code behind using the AutoGeneratingColumn. (Created a simple example here to reproduce the problem)

[Text Search Not Working for Column after Cell Alignment Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDgwi.gif)

```
  [<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CellAlignCenter" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>    

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch"
                 Height="22" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" 
                  Height="200" Width="300"
                  local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="dgTest_AutoGeneratingColumn">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>                  
                        <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>               
            </DataGrid.Resources>    
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>][2]
```

Code Behind:

```
   public static class DataGridTextSearch
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                "SearchValue",
                                                typeof(string),
                                                typeof(DataGridTextSearch),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

        public static string GetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(SearchValueProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSearchValue(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SearchValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                                        "IsTextMatch",
                                                                        typeof(bool),
                                                                        typeof(DataGridTextSearch),
                                                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static bool GetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public class SearchValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string cellText = values[0] == null ? string.Empty : values[0].ToString();
            string searchText = values[1] as string;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText))
                return cellText.Trim().ToLower().Contains(searchText.Trim().ToLower());
            else
                return false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name1 { get; set; }

        public string Name2 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            users.Add(new User() { Name1 = "John Doe", Name2 = "John Doe" });
            users.Add(new User() { Name1 = "Jane Doe", Name2 = "Jane Doe" });

            dgTest.ItemsSource = users;
        }

        private void dgTest_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            string headerName = e.Column.Header.ToString();
            Style styleAlignCenter = FindResource("CellAlignCenter") as Style;

            if (headerName == "Name1")
                e.Column.Width = 100;
            else if (headerName == "Name2")
            {
                e.Column.Width = 100;
                e.Column.CellStyle = styleAlignCenter;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will happen when I change the cell alignment from Code Behind.
Something missing in the Template definition for DataGridCell?
Appreciate for help and advice.

Comment: Looks just you're cover `DataGridCell.Style` in `dgTest_AutoGeneratingColumn`, It invalidates the default style in the DataGrid. Maybe you should try set `BaseOn` property of `Style` in "CellAlignCenter" style to base on default style you set in DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, however, when you change the style of the `DataGridCell` from code behind WPF will remove style elements (setters/triggers) from old style as well so just derive new style from old one and you will be fine.

Only thing need to be changed is XAML file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:SearchValueConverter x:Key="SearchValueConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="DefaultGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="local:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="CellAlignCenter" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultGridCellStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch"
             Height="22" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" 
              Height="200" Width="300"
              local:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="dgTest_AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultGridCellStyle}">
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```